# Using DRF FilterBackend

Tags: django-rest-framework

I use django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend

When use API I get an error:

> django_filters.exceptions.FieldLookupError: Unsupported lookup '_' for
>   field 'shop_rest.Inspect.id'

What does this mean that I can't use '_' in the name of the Model fields, or in the name of the application?

Comment: you can use underscore in model fields but not for model names or app names.

Comment: This is useful info. Thanks bro!